# Identify group leader in librdkafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, librdkafka

Is there a way to identify the group leader in librdkafka ?

As there is no way to pass a custom partition strategy, I am having some hack to serve the purpose. My specific consumer has to be the group leader if not I should exit.

Or is there a way to make sure there is no other consumer running with the current consumer group id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only way you can identify the leader of a consumer group is to enable the `cgrp` debug context (set the `debug` config property to `cgrp`) and then capture logs (with `log_cb` or the event API) and match this log line (which may change in future versions):

`1591771297.737 RDKAFKA-7-JOINGROUP: rdkafka#consumer-1: [thrd:main]: JoinGroup response: GenerationId 1, Protocol range, LeaderId rdkafka-b5751775-49f4-4ac8-a912-f5800f5bffbe (me), my MemberId rdkafka-b5751775-49f4-4ac8-a912-f5800f5bffbe, 1 members in group: (no error)`

The "`(me)`" part will only be included if the LeaderId is the same as the MemberId.

Comment: https://gitter.im/edenhill/librdkafka?at=5edfac64ee693d6eb3b34ae4